# how to get the correct size of NSString or check Whether it would fit in UILabel or Not?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an `UILabel` that can display only three lines of Text and its height and width are (312,44) inside an `UITableViewCell` what do I want to do that if `UILabel` text is more or getting ... (dot, dot) Then display the text on Alert view when user long press on that particular cell inside `UITableView`.

[image]

But the problem I am facing if text is doted inside the label it calculates `NSString` size less than  `UILabel` size in the below code. I am frustrating whats going wrong with it.

Here is `UILabel` inside `UITableView`

[image]

When I set "Breakpoint" in the code I am getting the **size** for the **below string** is (309.46,42.97) that is less than **lblSize**

@"Headline Description : Parker is located in 47 countries around the world Parker supports 142 divisions with 311 manufacturing locations in 47 countries globally. Our unrivalled industrial distribution network extends to approximately 13,000 locations globally. Through this extensive network of local, independent businesses, Parker can bring its products and services to customers in 104 countries globally. This includes continued penetration of the Parker Store network of industrial retail outlets, which is approaching 2,000 locations. "

```
-(IBAction)longGuestureTriggered:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPressGesture
{
    if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        UILabel* lbl=(UILabel*)longPressGesture.view;
        CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font constrainedToSize:lbl.bounds.size lineBreakMode:lbl.lineBreakMode];
        CGSize lblSize=lbl.bounds.size;
        if (size.height> lblSize.height && size.width>lblSize.width)
        {
            UIAlertView* alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Detail View" message:lbl.text delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alertView show];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more consistent if you allowed the text to always be displayed in an alertview regardless of the length of string?  That would dodge this particular bullet as well...

Comment: @trojanfoe no , actually I am allowed to display only ... doted text in alertview when user long press on the tabelview

Comment: OK.  What happens if you change `&&` to `||` in the code you post?

Comment: @trojanfoe nothing happens, condition always false becuase size width and height always returns less than

Comment: It should be `||` rather than `&&`.  Can show the values you are getting (i.e. `size` and `lblSize`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking for a size that fits the CURRENT label. You should ask for a size that fits a much taller label. So instead of

```
CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font constrainedToSize:lbl.bounds.size lineBreakMode:lbl.lineBreakMode];
```

you should use:

```
CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(lbl.bounds.size.width, 1000) lineBreakMode:lbl.lineBreakMode];
```